# How to compute the scalar $^{(4)}R_{\mu\nu} \; ^{(4)}R^{\mu\nu}$ in the ADM formalism in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature, adm-formalism

In the [Arnowitt-Deser-Misner (ADM) formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) in General Relativity, the line element takes the form
$$
ds^2 = - N^2 dt^2 + \gamma_{ij} ( N^i dt + dx^i) (N^j dt + dx^j) \ ,
$$
where $\gamma^{ij}$ is the spatial 3D metric and $t$ is the time coordinate, and $N$ and $N^i$ are the lapse function and shift vector respectively (both $N$ and $N^i$ are Lagrange multipliers and are not physical degrees of freedom).

In pretty much every treatment on this topic, the full (4D) Ricci scalar $^{(4)}R$ is shown to take the form
$$
^{(4)}R = \; ^{(3)}R + \frac{E_{ij}E^{ij} - E^2}{N^2}
$$
where $^{(3)}R$ is the 3D Ricci scalar (built out of the 3D metric $\gamma_{ij}$, using the notion of Christoffel symbols arising there), and $E_{ij}/N$ is the extrinsic curvature tensor, where
$$
E^{ij} = \; \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial \gamma_{ij}}{\partial t} - \nabla_{i} N_{j}- \nabla_{j} N_{i} \right)
$$
with $\nabla_{i}$ the 3D covariant derivative (built out of $\gamma_{ij}$ alone), and $E$ is
$$
E = \gamma^{ij} E_{ij} \ .
$$

**Question:** Is there a similar decomposition of the (4D) Ricci *tensor*? I am trying to compute the scalar quantity
$$
S:= \; ^{(4)}R_{\mu\nu}\; ^{(4)}R^{\mu\nu}
$$
in the ADM formalism, and cannot figure it out. My guess is that $S \propto\; ^{(3)}R_{ij}\; ^{(3)}R^{ij}, \; E^2$ but am unsure how to proceed in the calculation.

Comment: You can start with the Gauss-Codazzi equation: $$\mathcal{R}_{abcd}=h^m_ah^n_bh^s_ch^t_dR_{mnst}-(K_{ac}K_{bd}-K_{ad}K_{bc})$$  and start contracting with the space-time metric $g_{ab}$. Here $K_{ij}=E_{ij}$ and $\mathcal{R}\cdot$ is the 3d riemannian curvature

Comment: @KP99 What is $h$ here? Thanks

Comment: h is same as the $\gamma_{ij}$ metric

Comment: I would recommend you to go through the first few chapters of **3+1 Formalism and Bases of Numerical Relativity** by Eric Gourgoulhon. Contains all the necessary derivations and explains various caveats well.